# Hong Kong Cantonese: Derogatory Terms For Mainlanders

Tags: cantonese, word-requests

What derogatory terms are there for mainlanders in Hong Kong Cantonese?

I know there are a lot of terms that start with 北 but I'm not sure of specific ones.

Comment: Why do you want to know this kind of things? @user3306356

Comment: @zbz.lvlv why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one with 北 could be 北姑 or 北佬.

There are many other derogatory terms for Mainlanders, including:

- 阿燦
- 表叔, 表姐
- 强国人
- 皇虫, 蝗虫

Refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainland_Chinese#Names_2), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/3cl8xq/derogatory_slang_towards_foreigners/) and [this](http://en.cncurrent.com/on-the-use-of-derogatory-terms-in-hong-kong/).

Comment: The first 2 (阿燦, 表叔, 表姐) is used in the 80's (more as in Derogatory) while 强国人, 皇虫 is more recent (more as in Hostility)

Comment: Good answer. @user3306356 consider accepting it?

Comment: Hongkongers don't say 北佬.